# build fails on LightSwitch: Duplicate items are not supported by the "Resource" parameter

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-lightswitch

As soon as I create a new LightSwitch Desktop Application (Not HTML) and Add a Data Source using an existing database in SQL Server, and build the project it fails and say

> The item "......\MyDataSource.csdl" was specified more than once in
>   the "Resources" parameter and both items had the same value
>   "MyDataSource.csdl" for the "LogicalName" metadata. Duplicate items
>   are not supported by the "Resource" paramter unless they have
>   different values for the "LogicalName" metadata.

When I delete the **MyDataSource** under the **Data Sources** folder in the Server project, the solution build successfully. As soon as I define a new data source (pointing to any database in the SQL Server) and try to build the solution it fails with the same error.

I haven't add any screen and I haven't edit or add any custom code, just creating a new project and adding a data source, the project fails to build!

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065997/duplicate-items-are-not-supported-by-the-resources-parameter), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7810758/how-to-solve-a-duplicate-items-error-in-the-resources-parameter), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10065997/duplicate-items-are-not-supported-by-the-resources-parameter) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14889973/the-item-was-specified-more-than-once-in-the-resources-parameter-duplicate-it) but didn't find the proper answer to this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have encountered this problem before and didn't find any solution. But this time I did my best to find it out why a simple *LightSwitch* project (with no custom code, even with no screen and just with one data source added) cannot build successfully.

I tried to create new *LightSwitch* projects in different directories and with different names and with one of these tries I see it builds successfully! So what was the difference? I thought there may be something with *Project Name* or *Data Source Name* but it was not the case. Here is the point:

> Don't create LightSwitch application in a directory that contains space, **The whole directory path containing the LightSwitch project should not contains any space.**